# neo4j batch import crawls when property names are unique

Tags: neo4j

I am importing half million nodes in neo4j each with two property.. using batch_import utility.

each node represents a url and one of the property is the hash of the url.

The loading is very slow . it takes more than 3 hours for sure.

I tried loading a similar graph with generate.sh, and it loads in seconds.

my questions is : is having url hash as a property impacting the import in any way?

Comment: I took a profile and it looks like it is looping inside CSVReader.parseline()...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved... I had a " in the url and CSVParser got stuck on that...
Escaped it and things get created in 18 secs... :-)

Answer (score 1):

Glad you solved it. We've been playing around with [csvstat](http://csvkit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/scripts/csvstat.html) to try and identify that type of problem with stray quotation marks.